# Securing paths by userID param

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Data is structured like so:

```
leads
|__(ID)
   |__name
   |__email
   |__userID
```

Current firebase rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "leads": {
        ".indexOn": ["userID"],
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
}
```

This only secures the data if the user is not logged in.  I'd like to add an additional layer of protection to ensure that the logged in user cannot read any leads where `auth.uid !== userID`, but I'm having trouble structuring it above.

I thought this would work but the parent `".read": "auth !== null"` seems to override it.

```
{
  "rules": {
     "leads": {
        ".indexOn": ["userID"],
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth !== null",
        "$id": {
          ".read": "data.child('userID').val() === auth.uid"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule actually works.  The pathway I was using to run the simulation was with an ID of another parent node, so the actual data didn't exist and the simulation failed.

Answer (score 0):

When you grant access to any node to a user, you are implicitly giving that user access to that node *and everything under it*.  You can't cut off access to a child that someone has been given access to read at a higher level.  When you gave access to "leads" for all authenticated users, your rule for "$id" under that actually has no effect at all for authenticated users.

Comment: Ah, so should I remove that part and just grant access under the `$id` of each?  I suppose it may require a restructure of my data but I was hoping that I could give authenticated users access to their leads only on the DB level; both on the index page and on the individual lead view page.  I suppose I could just grant authenticated users access to the nodes then block access on the model layer.